# SQL query to join 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to SQL, so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even called a join.

I have 4 tables, with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey (
    id           serial    PRIMARY KEY,
    title        text,
    password     text
);

CREATE TABLE question (
    id           serial    PRIMARY KEY,
    surveyId     integer   REFERENCES survey(id),
    value        text
);

CREATE TABLE answer (
    id           serial    PRIMARY KEY,
    questionId   integer   REFERENCES question(id) ,
    value text
);

CREATE TABLE vote (
    id           serial,
    questionId   integer   REFERENCES question(id),
    answerId     integer   REFERENCES answer(id)
);
```

Given a specific `survey.id` (surveyId), I need to:

1. Find all question rows where `question.surveyId` = `surveyId`
2. For each question row found in (1), find all answer rows where `answer.questionId` = `question.id`
3. For each of the answers found in (2), find all vote rows where `vote.answerId` = `answer.id`.
4. Return a count of vote rows for each unique answerId.

So if I have the following test data:

```
question
=============
id | surveyId
1  | 3
2  | 3
3  | 3
4  | 5
5  | 6


answer
===============
id | questionId
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 3


vote
==========================
id | questionId | answerId
1  | 1          | 1
2  | 1          | 2
3  | 1          | 1
4  | 2          | 3
5  | 4          | 22
```

If the initial `surveyId` is 3, then I would expect the result of this query to be:

```
answerId | count
================
1        | 2
2        | 1
3        | 1
```

Is there any way to do this as a single SQL query?

Comment: have you tried joining tables?

Comment: If you read my question, I mentioned that I don't know what I'm doing - I don't know how to do a join, I don't even know if this would require a join.

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing then maybe a good start would be to learn about SQL JOINS http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: If you want to query more than 1 table, you'll **always** need a join (or a union, to be complete) (or a cartesian product, to be even more complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query you need:

```
SELECT v.answerId, COUNT(*) 
FROM survey AS s 
     INNER JOIN question AS q ON s.id = q.surveyId
     INNER JOIN answer AS a ON q.id = a.questionId
     INNER JOIN vote AS v ON a.id = v.answerId
WHERE  s.id = 3 -- This's your specific value of surveyId
GROUP BY v.answerId 
ORDER BY v.answerId
```

But this query can be optimized. You can give up single join given the relations of your tables:

```
SELECT v.answerId, COUNT(*) 
FROM survey AS s 
     INNER JOIN question AS q ON s.id = q.surveyId AND s.id = 3
     INNER JOIN vote AS v ON q.id = v.questionId
GROUP BY v.answerId 
ORDER BY v.answerId
```

And note that you cannot create a such set of test data. Because the value of answerId from table `vote` violates foreign key constraint `answerId` from this table. `22` is not present in table `answer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.answerId
  , vote = COUNT(v.vote) 
FROM survey s
  INNER JOIN question q
    ON s.surveyid = q.surveyId
  INNER JOIN answer a
    ON q.questionId = a.questionID
  INNER JOIN vote v
    ON a.answerId = v.answerId
WHERE s.surveyID = @yourValue
GROUP BY a.answerId
```

Is what I think you are looking for.